# Auto Update Google Chat Status Message

Tags: random, chat, status

I need to change my gmail chat status message frequently and set it to one of 10 predefined messages every X minutes. How can I do that? There should be a solution for this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. When we did it a couple of years back, we used python with xmpp and tinkered with the code talked about in here http://sathyaphoenix.wordpress.com/2010/08/03/finding-invisible-friends-and-dynamically-updating-your-status-in-google-chat-using-xmpp-scripts-linux-python-ubuntu/

Another link that shows up in google these days that you might want to consider is: http://bluegray.co.za/content/setting-google-talk-status-python-xmpp

All you need to do is set up an authenticated connection with the gmail xmpp server using xmpp python modules and send your custom text as a (Show, Status) Node object.